# How can I make this php script for OpenCart not to choose the latest products automatically

Tags: php, opencart

The below php script is from OpenCart and choose the latest products automatically but I would like to choose which once that should be shown from the modul section myself. I think it should be choosen by ID but I'm no good at php.

Would be very happy for help, the section is Senast inlagda produkterna

Thanks
anweb

```
<div class="sidebarHome">
<div class="featuredBox">
    <p class="heading">Actout Mindfulness</p> 

    <ul class="btn">
        <?php $i=0; foreach ($products as $product): $i++; ?>
            <li class="prod<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul> 

    <ul class="items">
        <?php $i=0; foreach ($products as $product): $i++; ?>
            <li class="prod<?php echo $i; ?>">
                <?php if ($product['thumb']): ?>
                    <div class="img">
                        <a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>" title="<?php echo $product["name"] ?>"><img src="<?php echo $product['thumb']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>" /></a>
                        <?php if ($product['special']): ?>
                            <span class="promo">Promo</span>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
                     <h2><a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>"><?php echo $product['name']; ?></a></h2>
                <?php if ($product['price']): ?>
                    <p class="price"><a href="http://www.actout.se" target="_blank">www.actout.se</a></p>
                <?php endif; ?>      
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>    
</div>
```

Comment: You supplied the code from the "View" section of the site...    What you need to do is edit the model and/or the database to query based on a list you select...    You then need to modify the admin section to include the select...  What version of opencart are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Anweb,

What you are describing can be dealt with via a different module. Use the feature module then you can select the products you want to show. If you want the module to be titled as Latest then you can edit

Store/language/English/module/featured.php

Replace;

```
$_['heading_title'] = 'Featured';
```

With;

```
$_['heading_title'] = 'Latest';
```

There are also extensions on the opencart site that will allow you to modify the module names within administration.

Comment: A much professional solution would be to duplicate the *Featured* module and then edit the language files. Your solution would completely 'remove' the original *Featured* module.